# GROUP BY one field, keeping other fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, aggregate

Base table `bod` with three fields:

```
| BOFORM_ID | FEINBOD | MAECHTBOD | 
+-----------+---------+-----------+
|   3301211 | fSms    |        50 |
|   3301211 | mSfs    |       150 |
|   3301231 | fSms    |       200 |
|   3301312 | Ss      |       150 |
|   3301312 | Su2     |        50 |
```

I'd like to

1. Group by `BOFORM_ID`
2. get the maximum value from `MAECHTBOD`
3. while keeping the associated `FEINBOD` from the same row as the maximum of `MAECHTBOD`.

I don't know how to implement step 3.

My desired output:

```
| BOFORM_ID | FEINBOD | MAECHTBOD | 
+-----------+---------+-----------+
|   3301211 | mSfs    |       150 |
|   3301231 | fSms    |       200 |
|   3301312 | Ss      |       150 |
```

Comment: Look up windowing functions (particularly PARTITION BY)... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @JoePhillips ... MS Access is a different Microsoft product and uses the JET/ACE SQL dialect not T-SQL. ACE does not support window functions.

Comment: @Parfait Indeed. I must've read the tags wrong

Answer (score 2):

You can use *correlated* subquery :

```
SELECT b.*
FROM bod as b
WHERE MAECHTBOD = (SELECT MAX(b1.MAECHTBOD) FROM bod as b1 WHERE b1.BOFORM_ID = b.BOFORM_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider joining your unit level data to aggregate query. This approach would be more efficient than correlated subquery which calculates the aggregate for *each* row of outer query and not once as below.

```
SELECT t.BOFORM_ID, t.FEINBOD, t.MAECHTBOD 
FROM myTable t
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT sub_t.BOFORM_ID, MAX(sub_t.MAECHTBOD) AS MAX_BOD
   FROM myTable sub_t
   GROUP BY sub_t.BOFORM_ID
) AS agg
ON t.BOFORM_ID = agg.BOFORM_ID AND t.MAECHTBOD = agg.MAX_BOD
```